# Branching process second moment problem.

Tags: probability

Let $X_i^{(n)}$ be IID nonnegative integer valued with mean $\mu<\infty$ and variance $0<\sigma^2<\infty$. We define $Z_0 := 1$ and $Z_{n+1} := \sum_{i=1}^{Z_n} X_i^{(n+1)}$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ and we will write $E_n[~\cdot~]$ as shorthand for $E[~\cdot~ | \mathcal{F}_n]$.

I have shown that $M_n := Z_n/\mu^n$ is a martingale. The next part of the problem says to show $E_n[Z_{n+1}^2] = \mu^2 Z_n^2 + \sigma^2 Z_n$, but I am getting a different answer.

I reason as follows:
$$
E_n[Z_{n+1}^2] = E_n\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{Z_n} X_i^{(n+1)}\right)^2\right]
= E_n\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i^{(n+1)}1_{\{Z_{n}\geq i\}}\right)^2\right]
$$
$$
= E_n\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} [X_i^{(n+1)}]^21_{\{Z_{n}\geq i\}} +\sum_{i\neq j}^{\infty} X_i^{(n+1)}X_j^{(n+1)}1_{\{Z_{n}\geq i,j\}} \right]
$$
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[[X_i^{(n+1)}]^2]1_{\{Z_{n}\geq i\}} +\sum_{i\neq j}^{\infty} E[X_i^{(n+1)}]E[X_j^{(n+1)}]1_{\{Z_{n}\geq i,j\}}
$$
$$
=(\mu^2+\sigma^2)\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{\{Z_n \geq i\}} + \mu^2\sum_{i\neq j}^\infty 1_{\{Z_n \geq i,j\}}
$$
$$
= (\mu^2+\sigma^2)Z_n + \mu^2 Z_n^2 
$$
and we see that an extra $\mu^2 Z_n$ has appeared compared to the answer.
Where have I gone wrong? I can't find my error.

Comment: The set $\{Z_n\geq i\}$ is an event, hence has a certain probability of occuring. When you take your expectation inside the sum in the third line, somehow you don't put the indicator of the event inside the expectation. As well, in the 4'th step, the second sum likely needs to be over $i=j$.

Comment: @Alex the set $\{Z_n \geq i\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable so $E_n[X 1_{\{Z_n \geq i\}}] = 1_{\{Z_n \geq i\}}E_n[X]$. I don't know what you mean the sum "likely" needs to be over $i=j$. All I have used here is $(\sum a_i)^2 = \sum_i a_i^2 + \sum_{i \neq j} a_ia_j$, I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Ah. It would help to clarify that $E_n$ is notation for a conditional expectation. My comment about the double indices is when you write $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{Z_n\geq i,j}$ and I mean that there's probably no $j$ there.

Comment: I see the typo you were referring to now, thanks. The question still remains though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the second sum that's wrong in the second-to-last step. You have $\sum_{i\neq j}1_{Z_n\geq i,j}=Z^2_n$. This is not right. There are a total of $Z_n^2$ index pairs and you are not summing over the equal ones, making the correct value of the sum $Z_n^2-Z_n$, which cancels one factor of $\mu^2.$